# Query openldap password policy

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Everything work great, I am able to query hosted() openldap but I am not able to fetch some attribute like `pwdExpireWarning, pwdMinLength, pwdInHistory, pwdExpireWarning`.

- first I fetch the policy name `ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.server -x -D "cn=user01,ou=App,ou=Systems,o=myOrg" -W -s sub "cn=user02" pwdpolicysubentry`

--- > `dn: cn=user02,ou=Web01,ou=System,o=myOrg`
----> `pwdpolicysubentry: cn=Standard Customer Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config`

- Second `ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.server -x -D "cn=user01,ou=App,ou=Systems,o=myOrg" -W -b "cn=Standard Customer Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config" -s base "(objectclass=*)" pwdMaxage`

---Err--> `No such object (32)`
---Err--> `Additional information: The search base entry 'cn=Standard Customer Policy,cn=Password Policies,cn=config' does not exist`

I tried to bypass the white space like (Standard\ Customer\ Policy) but nothing happens.

What is wrong with my ldapsearch command?
I am extremally frustrate about that.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using any LDAP Browser (GUI),

- search and find a user in a tree.
- On a hit there will be his attributes listed.
- Right mouse click on the users policientry.
- Choose localize in Dir tree or show in directory tree.
  (There will be pwdExpireWarning, pwdMinLength, pwdInHistory, pwdExpireWarnin, etc. displayed.)

NOW (attention):

- copy your real dn of the policy Entry or
- Check your logs "such logs" in Apache LDAP Browser.
  You will see your right "cn=Standard Customer Policy.....".
  That is to be used in your -b (base parameter).

Give it a chance.

Comment: OP is using the command line utilities. Please read the question.